# Generate constructor for superclass in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

Given simple class hierarchy

```
abstract sealed class Base(id: String)

case class Child1(id: String, value: Int) extends Base(id)

case class Child2(id: String, value: Long, file: File) extends Base(id)
```

can I use macros or something like that to avoid passing **id** to Base (and instruct compiler to generate this for me)? With single argument it's not that hard to pass it, but in case of several arguments it becomes uncomfortable.

Or if I could omit specification of **id** in child classes and make compiler generating ones for me from base class?

Comment: thank you!  this has been on my todo list to ask for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make Base as a trait:

```
sealed trait Base {
  val id: String
}

case class Child1(id: String, value: Int) extends Base
case class Child2(id: String, value: Long, file: File) extends Base
```

Comment: I don't think you have to write the `val` in front of `id` in the case classes. All constructor params are `vals`.

Comment: it's fine, thanks. Still I'm wondering if it's possible to generate constructors of sub-classes with parameters from parent class?

Comment: @jdevelop i'm not that good at macros, but as i remember from Evgene Burmarko's talk on ScalaDays2013, currently macros can't generate first-class entities (classes, traits)

Comment: Would be nice to abstract over this boilerplate, but I don't think that's possible now.

Comment: I think macro annotations might help here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html.